# Avro -> Parquet -> Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, parquet

I have a java program that uses the AvroParquetWriter to create parquet files.

I can put those files in S3 (AWS).

Having done that, I want to create an external table to query the parquet records using Spark SQL.

Is this possible?  All experiments I've tried suggest that Spark, at query time, cannot read the files created by the AvroParquetWriter.

If it is possible, what must I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to set `WRITE_OLD_LIST_STRUCTURE` in the hadoop configuration, as follows:

```
        Configuration hadoopconf = new Configuration() {{
            setBoolean(AvroWriteSupport.WRITE_OLD_LIST_STRUCTURE, false);
            this.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain");
        }};

        ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(path)
                .withSchema(contact_schema)
                .withConf(hadoopconf)
                .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your AvroParquetWriter, but this has worked for me since you can query parquet files directory via spark sql like this ...

```
PATH= '.../data.parquet'
spark.sql("select * from parquet.`{}`".format(PATH)).count()
```

You can also create an external table too like this ...

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db.table
(
C1 INT,
c2 TIMESTAMP,
c3 STRING,
etc...
)
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '.../data.parquet'
```